# Use IIS7 URL Rewriting to redirect all requests

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting

I have a .NET site that I am taking down and I plan on redirecting all requests to `www.mysite.com` using a rewrite rule in the `web.config`. Should be a simple task, but it's not. I've removed all the content from the filesystem except a single `Default.aspx` page and a default `web.config` with the following rewrite rule:

```xml
<rule name="Redirect All" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^(www\.)?mysite\.com(/.+)$" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="www.mysite.com" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

If I request `www.mysite.com/garbage.aspx` the server is still trying to look up `garbage.aspx`, or any other url I provide just as if the rewrite rule was not there.
Very frustrating. Ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you want to redirect ALL requests to your new site?  If so, this should do it:

```
<match url=".*" />
```

Comment: Shouldn't the regex above effectively accomplish the same thing since all requests will be to some page in mysite.com? I have a similar rule for canonical urls that works fine. I dont really see where I'm messing up.

Comment: I'm far from a regex expert, but I think it has to do with your groupings in the regex, and the way the IIS rewriter uses them.  What happens when you try the regex I provided?  Sorry I can't be more helpful with this particular comment.

Comment: I ended up redirecting to a different website in which case your solution worked like a charm. However, I think I'd have to add a rule to negate an internal link or else the redirect rule would loop... something I think I would have had to do with my original rule as well. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: I didn't have a proper understanding of how the URL Rewrite module worked when I wrote this. "url" in the rule does not include the host name or the '/